# How to run custom "npm run" command in VSBuild task Azure DevOps. Or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: reactjs, azure, visual-studio, npm, azure-devops

I am setting up Azure Build and Publish pipelines for my company. I posted the yml file for the build pipeline in another question. [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71226901/first-time-azure-devops-user-tips-on-what-i-could-do-better-in-my-build-pipelin)

One of the projects in my VS solution is a .Net 5.0 project with a React ClientApp folder. This is part of the package.json file in this React folder:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.localDevelopment react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.localDevelopment react-scripts build",
    "build_localdevelopment": "env-cmd -f .env.localDevelopment react-scripts build",
    "build_development": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
    "build_staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",
    "build_production": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    ...
  },
```

The problem is that the VSBuild task in Azure Build pipeline automatically runs `npm run build`. I need a way to tell it to run one of these different scripts based off of the declared buildConfiguration variable. Is this possible?

If I can't do it from Azure is there a way to run a script in package.json that will automatically detect the build configuration, even outside of Azure?

Or am I doing this all wrong and need to follow a better pattern?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a thought: according to 12-factor apps, there is no environment specific build. There is only one build and then you release your software to deploy it to different environments. Furthermore you shuold configure your software i.e. using environment variables, not during build.

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann, That is a great suggestion. I will look into 12-factor apps, but to be honest I am pretty sure it would require a lot of rework to align our code with this standard.